# Looping and reading by line in Bash

Tags: bash, ssh

1. Read a file of server names (.txt) line by line
2. loop through each server name and connect by ssh

Any suggestions, comments, and ideas?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Suggestions: search this site and google before posting; don't expect us to do your homework for you, we'll help if you have specific problems but we won't do all of the work; . Comments: explain what you are trying to do, what operating system you are using, whether you connect to the servers with the same username and password, whether you have passwordless access etc etc. Ideas: Use a for loop.

Comment: What have you tried?  As mentioned before we are not going to simply do this for you. If you have a solution that is not working then we can often help with that but we will not do your work for you.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66154/ssh-causes-while-loop-to-stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
while read p; do
    ssh root@$p ...
done < server_names.txt
```

I have not tested it, but in principle it should loop over servers in server_names.txt and connect to them.

Comment: in principle it shouldn't work, unless you use the `-n` ssh option. And i'm even not talking about allowing root connections.

Comment: @BatchyX why would you need the `-n` option? You can connect without it and run commands perfectly well. `-n` is needed if you want to run in the background. Also this kind of `root` access is often standard, when connecting to different nodes of a cluster for example.

Comment: @terdon: you need the `-n` option because otherwise, ssh will read and eat up stdin and transmit it to the remote host, just in case. also, allowing root access is a generally bad idea. You shouldn't encourage people to do that if it's not genuinely needed.

Comment: @BatchyX every lab I've worked in allowed root access between machines on the same network. You could not connect as root from outside the network but it was enabled internally. You may well be right and that is not a good idea but it is quite common. As for `-n` OK, sure it will protect from unwanted stdin reading but your comment said that this solution "shouldn't work" without `-n` which is most certainly not true.

Comment: @terdon: That's scary, to say the least. As for `-n`, i will not repeat myself. Please try before arguing. This is a known problem which has spawned plenty of questions already. Without `-n`, `ssh` WILL read stdin. Whether you like it or not. (and whether the remote command actually need input from stdin or not).

Comment: @BatchyX fair enough, I am pretty sure you know more about this than  do. All I am saying is that I have never used the `-n` option and I have done loops like the one suggested here many many times with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU Parallel and get it done in parallel:

```
parallel --slf servers.txt --nonall 'echo Hi from; hostname'
```

10 seconds installation:

```
 wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1